# Codeceptjs not able to scroll/swipe down without using an element

Tags: javascript, android, appium, codeceptjs

I am not able to swipe /scroll down in an Android application, I am using codeceptjs and following method but this method will act only on the visible element but I need to scroll down to the bottom of the page /on a specific element without using any element.

```
 static async Scroll(){
       let locator1 = '//android.widget.ScrollView' ;
       let locator2 = '//android.widget.TextView[@text="xxx"]';
       I.swipeTo(locator1,locator2,'up',30, 200, 800);}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. There doesn't seem to be much in the way of support/documentation/examples for this.

Comment: I just figured it out based on their code repo, we have to use x and y coordinates and pass it to performSwipe method it will just scroll based on the given x and y params and stoping at the right text you can use the grabTextFrom method

Comment: One quick question: have you had any luck with `swipeLeft()` or `swipeRight()`?

Comment: FWIW for me swipeLeft and swipeRight do not work at all

Answer (score 4):

I Got the answer for the same we just need to pass x and y objects to the performSwipe method like below :

I.performSwipe({x:300,y:1300},{x:300,y:300});

Comment: I wish I could up-vote your answer a hundred times. The official documentation is way off the mark: https://codecept.io/helpers/Appium.html (look up what it says for `performSwipe` there!!! Again, thank you very, very, very much!!!

Comment: I just created a PR to reflect this in the docs: https://github.com/codeceptjs/CodeceptJS/pull/3203. Thank you!

Comment: This answer solves it, but I'm still curious. Couldn't you somehow swipe the "background element"?